# Can I find out which of my beta testers have actually installed my Android app?

Tags: android, google-play, developer-console

We are conducting an A/B test via two different apps ("App A", "App B") on Google Play Store. Both apps are in **closed** Beta testing, ie. only accounts that are linked to supplied emails are allowed to test. A and B testers are on separate lists ("App A" uses "List A" and vice versa). Both lists have less than 25 testers.

Is there a way to find out, **which of our testers have actually installed the app?** I can see summaries, e.g. how many installations there have been and currently is, but I don't know how to drill down to user level. Is it even possible via Google Play Developer Console?

Comment: I recommend implementing Fabric's Answers; it gives you realtime data on all your releases. In comparison, Google's Dev Console is a very minimal viable product.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think so this kind of functionality is available with beta testing mode. However you can implement it by `Google Analytics` or by using your custom `API` which will be called when user runs app for first time.

Comment: Alas, this is probably the answer I have to accept.